# Text Box coming disabled in React JS using Type Script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tsx

I have used TSX file for loading text box in React JS as below :

```
<input type={'text'} value={employees.length > 0 ? employees[0].name : ""} id=
{'Name'} label={'Name'} name={'Name'} htmlFor={'Name'} />
```

Now when I load this file then we cant write any thing in text box.

So anyone can please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write anything because you have created a controlled component which means that the value of the input will always be whatever the `value` prop evaluates to - in this case `employees[0].name` or `""`.

With some minor adjustments you can make this work, either by making it a controlled component with an event listener which updates the value, or by making it an uncontrolled component.

> In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React component. The alternative is uncontrolled components, where form data is handled by the DOM itself.

More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

---

**Option 1 - Controlled component (recommended)**

To make a controlled component, you need to add the `onChange` event listener and have that update the variable that you pass into `value`. It's not clear from your question what `employees` is; if it's a state or prop variable or something else.

Assuming it's a state variable, you can do:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  let arr = this.state.employees.slice();
  arr[0].name = e.target.value;
  this.setState({employees: arr});
}

render() {
  let {employees} = this.state;
  return (
    <input type={'text'} onChange={this.handleChange} value={employees.length > 0 ? employees[0].name : ""} id={'Name'} label={'Name'} name={'Name'} htmlFor={'Name'} />
  );
}
```

---

**Option 2 - Uncontrolled component**

You only need a slight modification to make your input an uncontrolled component. Simply replace `value` with `defaultValue`:

```
<input type={'text'} defaultValue={employees.length > 0 ? employees[0].name : ""} id={'Name'} label={'Name'} name={'Name'} htmlFor={'Name'} />
```

---

As a side note, you don't need to wrap string literals in brackets. So instead of `<input type={'text'} ...` you can just do `<input type='text' ...`, if you prefer.